# smallest distance to place the capital?

Tags: geometry

A country has four cities where should the capital be built. it is desirable that the sum of distances of the cities from the capital be as small as possible?
how do i solve it ?

Comment: Sounds like homework.  What Mathematica code have you tried?

Comment: no its not a homework its and exercises im solving before the exam

Comment: Is this related in any way to [Mathematica](http://wri.com), the software?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the capital is called the [*geometric median*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median) of the points.  The wikipedia article mentions [specific results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Special_cases) for four coplanar points.

**Update:** If the alternative interpretation of @DavidG.Stork and @YNK is correct, the solution is trivial: for each of the four cities, calculate the sum of distances to the other three cities, and the minimum of these four sums indicates which city should be the capital.

Comment: Please re-read the question, which is really:  *choose which of four candidate locations minimizes the sum of the distances to the other three cities.*

Comment: I doubt that interpretation, which would yield a trivial problem.  @NourSuccarieh, please clarify.

Comment: I go with the interpretation of David G. Stork. Actually, I was about to ask NourSuccarieh  to clarify this part of his question when the comment from David appeared. If NourSuccarieh confirms this, geometric median does not offer a solution to the problem, because the locations in question are all fixed in 2D-space.